# ECS :Define varying count of tasks for containers inside task definiton

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I read the AWS doc which recommends to club containers within task definition based on relevance.
Like for example if I have web tier and db tier .create 2 task definition instead of 1 .
In my case I need to run 2 db (for eg mongo and Cassandra )so i have clubbed them in a single task definition.
While defining service i need to specify different count of tasks to be run for both of them .How can i achieve this by specifying it in ECS Service.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation that recommends "clubbing"?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/application_architecture.html


"you should create task definitions that group the containers that are used for a common purpose, and separate the different components into multiple, separate task definitions" 

"You can group related containers in a task definition, such as linked containers that must be run together"

Answer (score 1):

You split your single task definition `db-tier` that contains both Mongo and Cassandra into two separate task definitions. This way you don't have to club them together and you can set number of replicas individually.

But notice that containers in separate task definitions cannot communicate with each other out of the box (to use `link`, tasks must be clubbed), for this you would have to hardcode stuff, or use some kind of service discovery. But I don't think that your two databases are communicating with each other so that is not an issue.

Comment: True, they are not communicating with each other but this thought of having them together in a single task defn came up as i wanted them to land on the same container instance(EC2).